# Prevent Events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have two div, Outer Div and Inner Div, both  the `div` attached with click event.
whenever i click inner div it alert outer div also, i want to prevent the event handler of Outer div when i click the Inner Div in Javascript

Here is my Javascript

```
function funOne()
{
   //event.stopPropagation();
   alert('Outer Div')
}

function funTwo()
{
  //event.stopPropagation();
  alert('Inner Div')
}
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7r4hhzo0/)

Comment: Where are the events?

Comment: event.stopPropagation() is this not working for you ?

Comment: Check here. http://jsfiddle.net/7r4hhzo0/2/

Comment: It works for me. Both IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your fiddle check it out :

```
<div class="second" onclick="funTwo(event)"></div>

function funTwo(event)
{
event.stopPropagation();
alert('Inner Div')
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7r4hhzo0/4/

Answer (score 2):

Using `stopPropagation` should work to stop propagation from the child div to the parent div, but you functions are lacking an event object.

```
function funOne(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('Outer Div')
}

function funTwo(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('Inner Div')
}
```

You also need to pass the event when you call the function:

```
<div class="first" onclick="funOne(event)">
    <div class="second" onclick="funTwo(event)"></div>
</div>
```

Note that `stopPropagation` only works for child/parent situations. If the one div merely *appears* to be inside another div, `stopPropagation` does nothing.

Comment: `e` is going to be `undefined`.

Comment: @dfsq Why do you think so?

Comment: @Xufox OP provided a demo, it's very easy to test.

Comment: @Xufox Because, according to the jsfiddle in the question, the functions are called without parameters.

Comment: @Juhana Event handlers always have the event object as the first argument (if you do it with `addEventListener` anyway).

Comment: @Xufox Yeah, but the OP isn't doing it with `addEventListener`.

Comment: @Xufox Are you sure :) just open a fiddle and try it. note, that it's inline event handlers, not addEventListener.

Comment: @woz: Can you please elaborate on `If the one div merely appears to be inside another div, stopPropagation does nothing.`

Comment: @Navendu After checking the jsFiddle from the OP, I guess this isn't really relevant to his situation. I meant that the inner div has to be a child HTML element of the parent; you can't use CSS to position one div inside another and expect `stopPropagation` to work.

Answer (score 1):

Check here you missed to defined event.

```js
function funOne(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('Outer Div')
}

function funTwo(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('Inner Div')
}
```

```css
.first{width:600px; height:600px; background:yellow}
.second{width:100px; height:100px; background:orange; position:relative; top:50%; left:50%; margin-left:-50px; margin-top:-50px}
```

```html
<div class="first" onclick="funOne(event)">
 <div class="second" onclick="funTwo(event)"></div>
</div>
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7r4hhzo0/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function funOne(e)
  {
     e.stopPropagation();
    alert('Outer Div')
  }

   function funTwo(e)
    {
      e.stopPropagation();
     alert('Inner Div')
  }
   </script>
```

You need to call these function like onclick="funOne(event);" and onclick="funTwo(event);"